# The joint PDF of $X$ and the square of $X$ exists?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, density-function

In general how can you find the joint pdf of $X$ and $X^2$ if it exists? Can $f(x,x^2) = f(x^2)$, under the assumption that both $X$ and $X^2$ are Gaussian?

Comment: Please improve your formatting. This [link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?rq=1) will help you.

Comment: Do you want arbitrary Gaussian $X$, or e.g. is it of zero mean?

Comment: $X^2$ can not be Gaussian as a Gaussian random variable can have a negative value.

Comment: I don't think that $f(X,X^2)$ has any meaning, because $f(X,X^2)=f(X^2|X)f(X)$ based on Bayes rule, but $f(X^2|X)=\delta(X^2)$ and the whole concept is ill defined. I think the joint density of these two does not exist.

Comment: @J.G. Yes. Considering that $X$ is zero mean and $X^2$ is Gaussian in the positive domain of $X$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$(X,X^2)$ doesn't have a (joint) density w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$ ($\because$ the distribution of $(X,X^2)$ is concentrated on the graph of $x\mapsto x^2$).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I really appreciate it. But the moments of $X^2$ can be computed using the moments of $X$. Hence, How do you describe this relationship between $X$ and $X^2$ in terms of distribution? e.g. $f(x,x^2) = f(x^2|x).f(x).$

Comment: @BhargobAryanKasyap Look at [these notes](http://www.ee.iitm.ac.in/~krishnaj/EE5110_files/notes/lecture16_General_transformations_of_RVs.pdf).

Comment: So, I wanted to confirm f(x) and f(x^2) exists using the change-of-variable technique but not the joint or the conditional?

Comment: @BhargobAryanKasyap That's right.